# Basic bag on the return value of a function on matlab

Tags: matlab, function, bag

Consider the matlab function that describe in the image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZUhy.jpg)

As I run this function, I get that y = 1 insted of y = 7 as expected.

Why is this happening?

any response will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't post code as images. Please type it out for us to read/copy.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `while` gets `false` from the first iteration and stop.

use `while (a>=v(j))` to resolve your issue.